# Undefined in accessing a nested object

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm having difficulty accessing a certain property within a layered object called `result`:

```
result Object {
  "additionalUserInfo": hg {
    "isNewUser": true,
    "providerId": "password",
  },
  "credential": null,
  "operationType": "signIn",
  "user": Object {
    "apiKey": "some_api",
    "appName": "[DEFAULT]",
    "authDomain": "firebase.firebaseapp.com",
    "createdAt": "1579042072524",
    "displayName": null,
    "email": "qp@email.com",
    "emailVerified": false,
    "isAnonymous": false,
    "lastLoginAt": "1579042072524",
    "phoneNumber": null,
    "photoURL": null,
    "providerData": Array [
      Object {
        "displayName": null,
        "email": "qp@email.com",
        "phoneNumber": null,
        "photoURL": null,
        "providerId": "password",
        "uid": "qp@email.com",
      },
    ],
    "redirectEventId": null,
    "stsTokenManager": Object {
      "accessToken": "some_access_token",
      "apiKey": "some_api_key",
      "expirationTime": 1579045673373,
      "refreshToken": "some_refresh_token",
    },
    "tenantId": null,
    "uid": "some_uid",
  },
}
```

I want to access "some_access_token", but I can only go so far as `result.user`, but if I do `result.user && result.user.stsTokenManager` or

```js
if(result.user.stsTokenManager){
   console.log(result.user.stsTokenManager.accessToken)
}
```

I also tried `const accessToken = (((result || {}).user || {}).stsTokenManager || {}).accessToken` 
but still undefined

**Update**

This is how I'm attempting to access the variable, but still undefined.

```js
 const submitHandler = async (input) => {
        const { email, password } = input && input
        let result;
        try {
            result = await Firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        } catch (err) {
            switch (err.code) {
                case 'auth/email-already-in-use':
                    console.log("message", err.message)
            }
        }
        const token = (((result || {}).user || {}).stsTokenManager || {}).accessToken
        console.log("accessToken", token)


        // or

        if (result.user.stsTokenManager) {
            console.log(result.user.stsTokenManager.accessToken)
        }

        // or
        console.log(result && result.user.stsTokenManager.accessToken)
    }
```

I even tried lodash:

```
const accessToken = _.get(result, ['user', 'stsTokenManger', 'accessToken'])
```

but still undefined

The odd part is I can access `result.user.email`, `result.user, emailVerified`, `result.user.providerData`, `result.user.uid`, but I get `undefined` in `result.user.stsTokenManager`, `result.user.lastLoginAt`, `result.user.createdAt` even though when I `console.log(result)`, I can clearly see that the variables are populated.

Comment: if results is falsey, then `{}.user` for example will throw an error

Comment: Can't find a problem - `result.user.stsAccessToken` works for me. You haven't posted the actual code you're using. Are you sure you're looking at the right variable, and that the variable has the data you think it has?

Comment: when I do `console.log(result)` I get all the variables fine so I know they exist. I updated the code to show how I attempt to access the variables

Comment: I'm afraid this is just down to simple debugging, use it to navigate the result in memory or use the watch and you'll find out where the problem lies. P.S. this hurts my eyes - `(((result || {}).user || {}).stsTokenManager || {}).accessToken`

Comment: @James can you elaborate? How should I go about debugging?

Comment: @Kevvv by using the debugger on whichever IDE you use...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem you have to add, after:

`result = await Firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)`

the following line:

`const resData = await firebase.auth().currentUser.toJSON()`

In this way, you have access to all the data that you are looking for.
For example now you can get the `accessToken` with:

`resData.stsTokenManager.accessToken`

...

`resData.stsTokenManager.expirationTime`